# Twitter Embeded timeline not working in Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, twitter, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Following script using dispaly search result in timeline.

```
<html>

<a class="twitter-timeline"  href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23Some name"  data-widget-id="3733932158675216312320">Tweets about "#Some name"</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){ var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</html>
```

But the Html page not showing content in webbrowser in wp8. The Html page works fine Chrome firefox and IE

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the "IsScriptEnabled" property of the web browser control to "True".